# The different arguments options for a function with move semantics

Tags: c++, c++17, move

I need to make a member function that has an argument of `std::vector<int>` and uses the `move` semantics to steal the guts of it and place to a different `std::vector<int>` that is a member of class `T`.

```
class T {

std::vector<int> vec; 

public: 

void setVec(std::vector<int> vec_){ vec = std::move(vec_); }

}
```

Now my question is; What is the different and implications of having the following interfaces for `setVec` and which one should be used?

1 : `void setVec(std::vector<int> vec_)`

2 : `void setVec(std::vector<int>& vec_)`

3 : `void setVec(std::vector<int>&& vec_)`

Comment: Take your time to read the dupe, there's quite a lot of information there. If you have a question that's not directly addressed there, then edit the question.

Comment: For a data sink parameter such as this situation, my team would use option 1.  That puts the least burden on the caller, although we'd probably implement this one as a `std::swap` rather than `std::move`, but that's splitting hairs.

Comment: @cigien: The 'dupe' contains a lot of info on what the move semantics does and definition of r-value and l-value. That is all fine, however, I am more specifically questioning the impact of the suggested function interfaces and whether some `move` semantics would just end up being copies, like what happens if you had a `const`  in the argument

Comment: Did you read the second answer? It's an expansion of the accepted answer by the same user, and goes into a *lot* of detail, and addresses your concerns quite clearly, I think.

Comment: It's a mouthful, but `template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, std::vector<int>>, bool> = true> void setVec(T&& vec_){ vec = std::forward<T>(vec_); }` is the forwarding reference approach.